# How to preserve user logged in using Parse JS and Facebook SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk, session-variables

I'm using Parse Server +  Parse JS Sdk to handle user login through Facebook. Everything works fine until I refresh web browser. What data should I store after login process is done? I belive that FB `AccessToken` is important to keep Facebook Session, but what about Parse Session.

Current code:

```
login: function (callback) {
  console.log('loggin in...')
  Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn('user_likes,email', {
    success: function (parseUser) {
      if (!parseUser.existed()) {
        console.log('signed up and logged in!')
      } else {
        console.log('logged in!')
      }
      console.log('parse user is: ', parseUser.id)
      if (callback) { callback() }
    },
    error: function (parseUser, error) {
      console.log('login cancelled: ', error.message)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually store anything.  You can use the parse function:

```
Parse.User.current()
```

To see if there is already a user logged-in.

We made this function:

```
function userAuthenticated(){
    if(Parse.User.current() === null){
        return false;
    }

    if(Parse.User.current().authenticated()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response! As soon as I will have access to my code I will check if it's working and mark answer as accepted :) Maybe someone else would have the same issue.